# Insert into firebase real-time database with getuid instead of getkey

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am inserting data into the firebase real-time database and then getting the data and displaying it on a graph but when i insert into the database now i am using the unique `getkey()` method to insert the values but i would like to use the `getuid()` method as the user is already authenticated in the app. I'd like to know how I can change the `getkey()` to use the `getuid().`

**This is my current code:** The `getkey()` method is in the `setListneners()` method

```
FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference reference;
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_weight); 

    Btn_Display = findViewById(R.id.btn_display);
    graphView = findViewById(R.id.weight_graph);
    series =  new LineGraphSeries();
    graphView.addSeries(series);
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    reference = database.getReference("WeightGraph");

    setListeners();
}

   private void setListeners() {
    Btn_Display.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String id = reference.push().getKey();
            long x = new Date().getTime();
            int y = Integer.parseInt(weight.getText().toString());

            PointValue pointValue =  new PointValue(x, y);

            reference.child(id).setValue(pointValue);
        }
    });

    graphView.getGridLabelRenderer().setNumHorizontalLabels(2);
    graphView.getGridLabelRenderer().setNumVerticalLabels(2);

    graphView.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(new DefaultLabelFormatter(){
        @Override
        public String formatLabel(double value, boolean isValueX) {
            if(isValueX){
                return simpleDateFormat.format(new Date((long) value));
            }else{
                return super.formatLabel(value, isValueX);
            }
        }
    });
}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            DataPoint[] dataPoints = new DataPoint[(int) snapshot.getChildrenCount()];
            int index = 0;

            for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
                PointValue pointValue = dataSnapshot.getValue(PointValue.class);

                dataPoints[index] = new DataPoint(pointValue.getxValue(), pointValue.getyValue());
                series.resetData(dataPoints);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: FirebaseUser mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser(); then mAuth.getUid();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
  super.onStart();

  FirebaseUser mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()

  reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        DataPoint[] dataPoints = new DataPoint[(int) snapshot.getChildrenCount()];
        int index = 0;

        for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
            PointValue pointValue = dataSnapshot.getValue(PointValue.class);

            dataPoints[index] = new DataPoint(pointValue.getxValue(), pointValue.getyValue());
            series.resetData(dataPoints);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

    }
  });
}
```

Then you can get Uid

```
mAuth.getUid()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write the data under the user's UID instead of the key generated by `push()`, you'd do something like this:

```
String id = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
long x = new Date().getTime();
int y = Integer.parseInt(weight.getText().toString());

PointValue pointValue =  new PointValue(x, y);

reference.child(id).setValue(pointValue);
```

---

If you want to store a list of points for each user, you'd change that last line to:

```
reference.child(id).push().setValue(pointValue);
```

So this way you get a list of auto-generated (push) IDs under each UID.

Comment: Thank you this method works perfectly but now, I am having an issue getting my data from the database to my graph. As it cannot find the location. the `get data()` is part of my code above

Comment: My assumption is that it cannot find the data as the graph displays blank now